# Factorisation of tree level amplitudes from unitarity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, unitarity

Is there a simple argument to explain why tree level amplitudes must factorize on their pole into products of lower point tree level amplitudes, not by ispection of Feynman diagrams but as a conseguence of unitarity?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/585064/2451